# Framing Errors in Celery 3.0.1

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I recently upgraded to Celery 3.0.1 from 2.3.0 and all the tasks run fine. Unfortunately. I'm getting a "Framing Error" exception pretty frequently. I'm also running supervisor to restart the threads but since these are never really killed supervisor has no way of knowing that celery needs to be restarted. Has anyone seen this before?

```
2012-07-13 18:53:59,004: ERROR/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: Exception('Framing Error, received 0x00 while expecting 0xce',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/__init__.py", line 350, in start
    component.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 360, in start
    self.consume_messages()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 445, in consume_messages
    drain_nowait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 175, in drain_nowait
    self.drain_events(timeout=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 171, in drain_events
    return self.transport.drain_events(self.connection, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/transport/amqplib.py", line 262, in drain_events
    return connection.drain_events(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/transport/amqplib.py", line 97, in drain_events
    chanmap, None, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/transport/amqplib.py", line 155, in     _wait_multiple
    channel, method_sig, args, content = read_timeout(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/transport/amqplib.py", line 129, in read_timeout
    return self.method_reader.read_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/method_framing.py", line 221, in read_method
    raise m
Exception: Framing Error, received 0x00 while expecting 0xce
```

Comment: Not an expert and this is guess from the stack trace but, are you sure your task producers are writing messages into amqp in the correct version? Maybe you need to update the producer's version, flush old messages, or something like that.

Comment: I am currently facing the same problem. Could it be different AMQP lib on the worker and the task sender?

Comment: Hey Dan, have you solved this issue?

Comment: I was able to resolve it by moving by RabbitMQ server to a different (more powerful) server and making sure the various time/date settings were consistent across servers. That seemed to have fixed it.

Comment: Dan, thanks! Will check time/date settings. While researching I found out that whenever Celery connects to broker using 'localhost' everything works perfectly. Once I change that to IP or domain name - I get the same error. Couldn't come up with solution yet.

Comment: For what it's worth. I also ended up moving it to a more powerful machine so maybe there were some issues with the slower backend machine handling the queuing. Not entirely sure if that was the reason though but it's no longer an issue now.

Answer (score 5):

While I am not sure why this actually happens, switching from `amqplib` to `librabbitmq` helped me to overcome this trouble.

I haven't changed anything in configuration, just:

```
pip uninstall amqplib
pip install librabbitmq
```

And restarted celery workers.

Got this idea form https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/922

Comment: was running into this error with Kombu (the library that sits underneath Celery) and moving to librabbitmq from amqplib worked