# Celery error "Received 0x00 while expecting 0xce"

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I try to use **celery**. I have installed **rabbit-mq** by command from celery tutorial:

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
```

And all worked well while I write my code in one file and run it to test functionality. But when I tried to add my code in Django views, and then to do concurrent requests to my views, I got this kind of exception:

```
File "/home/kinmanz/PycharmProjects/GitFace/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 464, in drain_events
    return self.blocking_read(timeout)
  File "/home/kinmanz/PycharmProjects/GitFace/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 468, in blocking_read
    frame = self.transport.read_frame()
  File "/home/kinmanz/PycharmProjects/GitFace/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 251, in read_frame
    'Received {0:#04x} while expecting 0xce'.format(ch))
amqp.exceptions.UnexpectedFrame: Received 0x00 while expecting 0xce
```

I think that problem may be in concurrency of request, and I should somehow to make queue concurrent safe.

I use Python 3.5, Celery 4.0.0, RabbitMQ 3.5.7

---

Actually problem in **amqplib** see answer below.

Comment: Does your django views contain any celery related task calls ?

Comment: Not any, I have found description of the same problem here https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2066 problem actually about python3, and creator just have written he don't have any resources to solve that, may be there any others ways to solve that problem? May be you can suggest something about using Python3 + celery + concurrent request to cellery, so that I can get working variant.

Comment: I have managed to do something with this problem, anyway it seems that problem has been overcome but it's not so good way. I have tried to use redis, as result backend app = Celery('tasks', backend='redis://localhost', broker='pyamqp://'), and if somebody it will help see http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2014/05/18/setting-up-an-asynchronous-task-queue-for-django-using-celery-redis/ In the future I will add answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be for someone who has the same problem, I will list possible solutions that I have managed to find. If you know better solution please add your answer or comment mine.

If you are using **Python 2.x** then see that issue https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/922
problem actually in **amqplib** if it change on **librabbitmq** all should be working, it's quite easy to do, see:
[Framing Errors in Celery 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479647/framing-errors-in-celery-3-0-1)

---

But if you are using **Python 3.x** you can't solve that problem in that way, because there is no Python 3-compatible **librabbitmq** available, see that issue https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2066 but in that case you can change your result backend on **redis** for example:

***1) Install redis server:***

```
$ sudo aptitude install redis-server
```

***2) Change your app configuration***

```
app = Celery('tasks', backend='redis://localhost', broker='pyamqp://')
```

Some useful links about installation **redis**: [Setting up an asynchronous task queue for django using celery redis](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2014/05/18/setting-up-an-asynchronous-task-queue-for-django-using-celery-redis/) and [Celery-redis quick guide](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#redis)

---

Also for **Python 3** you can try to run celery worker in **Python 2.7** while your app is working on **Python 3**, in that case don't forget install **librabbitmq** instead of **amqplib**. (This way seems to be inconvenient)