# Celery error “Received 0x00 while expecting 0xce”

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, amqp

I use celery 4.3.0 and rabbitmq 3.6.6. There is also a Haproxy for balancing rabbitmq, but right now it only uses one rabbitmq node.

Timeout client/server in Haproxy 24 hours.

Sometimes I get an error and the task execution status is not returned, while the tasks continue to run:

```
 Received 0x00 while expecting 0xce
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/serv/app/mod_axmsg/dispatch.py", line 376, in execute
    result_value = func_meta.func(*task.args_list, **task.kwargs_dict)
  File "/var/www/serv/app/mod_rmc/libs/health.py", line 91, in update_all_health
    health.update_all_health()
  File "/var/www/serv/app/mod_core/libs/health.py", line 515, in update_all_health
    result.join()
  File "/usr/local/serv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 765, in join
    interval=interval, no_ack=no_ack, on_interval=on_interval,
  File "/usr/local/serv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 226, in get
    on_message=on_message,
  File "/usr/local/serv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/backends/asynchronous.py", line 188, in wait_for_pending
    for _ in self._wait_for_pending(result, **kwargs):
  File "/usr/local/serv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/backends/asynchronous.py", line 255, in _wait_for_pending
    on_interval=on_interval):
  File "/usr/local/serv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/backends/asynchronous.py", line 56, in drain_events_until
    yield self.wait_for(p, wait, timeout=1)
  File "/usr/local/serv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/backends/asynchronous.py", line 65, in wait_for
    wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/serv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/backends/rpc.py", line 63, in drain_events
    return self._connection.drain_events(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/serv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 323, in drain_events
    return self.transport.drain_events(self.connection, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/serv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 103, in drain_events
    return connection.drain_events(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/serv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 505, in drain_events
    while not self.blocking_read(timeout):
  File "/usr/local/serv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 510, in blocking_read
    frame = self.transport.read_frame()
  File "/usr/local/serv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 280, in read_frame
    'Received {0:#04x} while expecting 0xce'.format(ch))
amqp.exceptions.UnexpectedFrame: Received 0x00 while expecting 0xce
```

My code: celery.py

```
import logging

from app import db
from celery import Celery

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def make_celery(flask_app):
    broker = flask_app.config['AMQP_URL']
    celery = Celery('mod_celery', broker=broker, backend="rpc://")
    celery.conf.update(flask_app.config)

    class ContextTask(celery.Task):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with flask_app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery


def in_tx(task_function):
    def tx_wrapper(*args):
        try:
            task_function(*args)
            db.session.commit()
        except Exception as ex:
            msg = 'Could not execute task {}. Reason: {}.' \
                .format(task_function.__name__, str(ex))
            LOG.error(msg)
            db.session.rollback()
    return tx_wrapper
```

And file tasks.py

```
from app import celery
from .celery import in_tx


@celery.task(name='app.mod_celery.update_client_health_task')
@in_tx
def update_client_health_task(client_id):
    from app.mod_core.libs.health import update_client_health
    update_client_health(client_id)
```

What could be the problem? Please don't offer me redis.

I'm not a developer and I didn't write it the code, but I really need to figure it out. I'm new to python

Thanks.

Comment: Please show some code so we can understand what can cause the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Celery error "Received 0x00 while expecting 0xce"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703846/celery-error-received-0x00-while-expecting-0xce)

Comment: I can't use Redis because we use rabbitmq everywhere.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: I found similar errors in the official Celery community, but there is no solution yet (https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6335). But claim that this is because of the race condition in WSGI. 

In the latest version of Celery, this should have been fixed, but I can't check because Python needs to be updated.

Comment: Also, if you change the backend to RabbitMQ (no rpc), the problem disappears, but it loads RMQ very much